# Can I auto-discover jaxws:endpoints for beans.xml based on annotated @WebService classes / interfaces?

Tags: java, spring, maven, annotations, cxf

I created a cxf/spring project with:

mvn archetype:create -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.cxf.archetype -DarchetypeArtifactId=cxf-jaxws-javafirst

The resulting project has a HelloWorld.java interface annotated as a @WebService, and a HelloWorldImpl.java annotated with an endpointInterface=mypackage.HelloWorld.

There's a beans.xml file containing:

```
<jaxws:endpoint
   id="helloWorld"
   implementor="mypackage.HelloWorldImpl"
   address="/HelloWorld" />
```

If I want to add more services, it looks like I'm expected to keep adding new endpoints in beans.xml.  Since the classes are already annotated as @WebService, why can't it auto-discover any new services within some package / search path?  Is there some way I can configure this project to do that?

Basically, I'm just trying to avoid repeating myself.  The information is already going to be in the annotations so I don't want to have to edit additional files each time I add a service.

If I remove the jaxws:endpoint tag in beans.xml, and then `mvn install tomcat:run`, localhost:8080/myArtifactId just shows me a page saying there are not services defined.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the CXF you should know that all the endpoints you added are managed by the CXFServlet that uses Spring context to find them out. `beans.xml` is a Spring context's config file. So if you remove the `<jaxws:endpoint/>` node from that file your Spring context and hence the CXFServlet will have no way to find your service endpoints.

Comment: OK... I mean, I think I understand that, but what I'm asking is, is there any other way to do this?  I don't care if it's spring or not, maybe I've chosen an artifact that I shouldn't have.  I just want to create a maven project where I'm able to annotate a class with WebService and have an app server expose it as a soap service with  generated wsdl.  What are my options?  I realize that Spring is depending on this xml file but there must be some framework that scans the classpath for WebService annotations and exposes them.

Comment: Resteasy seems to find JAX-RS annotated classes at startup time without a hint of where those classes are. Isn't there a JAX-WS framework that provides this autodiscover feature?